# Issue with Zend framework 2 and netbeans Xdebug

Tags: netbeans, zend-framework2, xdebug

Hello I put xdebug in my wamp and it works. I am trying to use it on zend framework 2. My problem is that when I am put breakpoint I want to jump directly to my breakpoint. Now I have to pass too many files every time before I reach to my breakpoint. Can you give me advice? Btw I use netbeans 7.3 on windows 7

Comment: I also have the same issue... appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario ( Linux + Netbeans 7.3), I click **F5** (continue) to go to the next breakpoint.

Comment: In my scenario (and my problem) is that when I click F5 I pass through all files before I reach the breakpoint. And in my case I have to click F5 may be 20 times every time before I reach the breakpoint.

Comment: What happens when you start the debug using Ctrl + Shift + F5 ?

Comment: I don`t know how exactly I fixed the problem but now is almost ok. Now when I use CTRL+ F5 the netBenas opens http://localhost/zendd/public/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug. The true address is http://localhost/zendd/public/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug. Every time I have to remove index.php from url. When I remove index.php from Right click on project -> properties -> Run Configuration -> Index file I see nex error : Index File must be a valid relative URL.

Comment: And the last my question is how exactly to see value of all my variables using in the code. Now I see only $_POST, $_GET $_SERER and etc, but without for example $date when $date = 'test date'; I want when I am on the variable with mouse I see the value